# How would you address a younger step-parent / older step-child?

Tags: word-choice, words, culture, kinship-terms

Like this but way more insane: [Younger uncles and aunts](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27300/younger-uncles-and-aunts) (But I believe this sorta happened in [House of the Dragon](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/House_Targaryen/House_of_the_Dragon#Relationships), prequel / spin-off of of Game of Thrones)

[image]

Let's say widow Viserys Tanaka had daughter Rhaenyra Tanaka and later remarries Alicent Hajime. If Rhaenyra is older (or even about the same age) than Alicent, then how might they address each other?

I have a feeling based on Spy x Family that the step-parent might address the step-child as 1st name-san [Why does Yor call Anya as Anya-san instead of Anya-chan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67013/why-does-yor-call-anya-as-anya-san-instead-of-anya-chan)

But I guess what would be more important is how far apart in age they are, their relationship prior to the wedding, etc over their legal relationship.

Comment: It depends on their relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess such a situation is too rare to be discussed in general, but the following is likely.

- If Rhaenyra and Alicent has been friends, they would continue to call each other in the way they have been using.
- If Rhaenyra and Alicent know each other by the marriage, they would call each other like classmates. Use of san or first name alone is just personal choice depending on how they feel about each other.

---

If the House is sort of aristocratic that puts a lot of importance on formalites, Rhaenyra may call Alicent *okaasama*, but it is just as unlikely as R. calling A. *Mother* in English.

(Like Maki Shijo calling Kaguya as *obasama* in *Kaguya-sama*, it may be possible in extremely rich families, but I have simply no idea)

Comment: I was actually thinking of Kaguya-sama! Also like Code Geass and stuff. Lol. Thanks!